# how to delete programs in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

How to delete programs with all components ( Full Delete Program )

So that, for example, you delete a program I Firefox by

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove Firefox
```

But there are some additions are not deleted
For example:

> firefox-locale-en
>
> xul-ext-ubufox
>
> unity-scope-firefoxbookmark
>
> rhythmbox-mozilla

Comment: for this mode use `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove Firefox*` (add * mark at the end of package_Name)

Answer (score 1):

install synaptic if not:- `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Open **synaptic package manager** and search the app you want to delete then tick mark and and right click and select 'Mark for complete remove'.

Answer (score 0):

You can start GUI tool from command line named synaptic, enter:

> $ synaptic &

### Heading ##Command Line Package Management Tool :

apt-get is the command-line tool for handling packages. It is used for adding / removing / updating packages.

Uninstall / Delete / Remove Package

Just use the following syntax:

### Heading ##sudo apt-get remove {package-name}

For example remove package called mplayer, enter:

> $ sudo apt-get remove mplayer

Remove package called lighttpd along with all configuration files, enter:

> $ sudo apt-get --purge remove lighttpd

To list all installed package, enter:\

> dpkg --list
>   dpkg --list | less
>   dpkg --list | grep -i 'http'